# sudden 100 percent CPU usage in Postgresql

Tags: spring-boot, postgresql-11

We are using postgres sql on a 16 core cpu machine. We see a sudden spike cpu usage from a random command as can be seen in the command column of htop. The pg_stat_activity and connections are well under control. Need help resolving this.

We have a java spring boot application running over this application

[image: Hig CPU Usage]

Comment: No. Thanks for the response. Its 11.5.

Comment: "NaG6au" isn't a regular SQL command. You probably have been hacked

Comment: Any idea how to secure

Comment: Don't allow connections from outside of your network. Use a secure password for all users, or only allow SSH connections. Don't allow remote superuser connections. Don't use the superuser account for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I will do this exercise but howdo I fix my server immediately